# How to solve "exec: \"Python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown. for simple python script on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

I've tried things on the previous questions but none have seemed to work.

When I try to run docker container I receive this error:

```
docker run ....dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/....(omitting some information here)        
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"Python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

The file exists in the specified path.

Installable

```
    python-socketio==4.6.0
    fxcmpy==1.2.6
    pandas==1.0.5
    joblib==0.16.0
    DateTime==4.3
    schedule==0.6.0
    matplotlib==3.3.0
    numpy==1.19.1
    scipy==1.5.1
    scikit-learn==0.23.1
```

docker file:

```
    FROM python:3

    WORKDIR /usr/src/app

    COPY Final_Classifier_KNN_N=4.pkl .
    COPY my_functions.py .
    COPY KNN_FXCM_ALGO.py .
    COPY installables.txt .

    RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r installables.txt 

    CMD [ "Python", "./KNN_FXCM_ALGO.py" ]
```

I have tried to run this container using these commands:

```
- docker run .dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
- docker run -ti .dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
- docker run python3 .dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a docker problem. Unix like OS are case sensitive. This should do the trick.

`CMD ["python", "KNN_FXCM_ALGO.py"]`